# Передача строки в функцию Function(const string &stroka)

Tags: c++

Что такое const  и зачем оно здесь нужно? почему без const не передается строка в функцию?

```
class Object { 
      private: 
         string stroka; 
      public: 
         Object::Object(string &n) { Object::stroka = n;} 
} 

void main() { Object FAI("ss"); }
```

Comment: class Object
{
private:
 string stroka;
public:
Object::Object(string &n)
 {
  Object::stroka = n;}
}
void main()
{
 Object FAI("ss");
}
Ругается компилятор.

Comment: странный у вас код... `;` точно не пропустили? Зачем каждый раз `Object::` писать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка(`std::string`) в функцию передаётся и с `const` и без, а вот C-строка(просто текст между кавычек, например `"Text"`) без `const` передана быть не может, т.к будет создан временный объект `std::string`, который будет инициализирован C-строкой. Константная ссылка может и привязывается к временному объекту, тогда как неконстантная ссылка не может быть привязана к временному объекту.

Советую Вам почитать про ссылки и константы, это основа основ C++.

Answer (score 3):

Можно и без `const`, зависит от того, что должна делать функция.

Модификатор `const` означает, что строка, которая уходит в функцию, не будет внутри этой функции изменена.

Если функция должна модифицировать строку (например, это функция для удаления пробелов), то `const` нужно не ставить (иначе модифицировать строку не удастся).

Если, наоборот, функция не должна модифицировать строку (например, эта функция выдаёт значение по строке как ключу), то конечно будет работать и без `const` — но лучше поставить `const`. В этом случае если код функции по ошибке всё-таки попробует модифицировать строку, то он не откомпилируется. Это помогает отловить возможные ошибки.

---

Таким образом, можно считать `const` разновидностью документации: оно сообщает, может ли параметр быть изменён внутри функции.

---

Если у вас есть на руках `const string`, то у вас, понятно, не получится передать это функцию, которая принимает просто `string` или там `string&`. Причина этому — `const string` — это строка, которую *нельзя* изменять, а вот объявление функции без `const` означает, что функция может поменять строку. Чтобы поменять было таки нельзя, компилятор не даст вам это скомпилировать.

Comment: Почему компилятор ругается когда, я передаю строку
class Object
{
private:
 string stroka;
public:
Object::Object(string &n)
 {
  Object::stroka = n;}
}
void main()
{
 Object FAI("ss");
}

Comment: @aleshka-batman: Ну, покажите код и дайте вашу точную ошибку. (И прочитайте обновление ответа.)

Answer (score 1):

ixSci Рассказал Вам всё верно.

По поводу вот этого :

> Почему компилятор ругается когда, я передаю строку class Object {
>   private: string stroka; public: Object::Object(string &n) {
>   Object::stroka = n;} } void main() { Object FAI("ss"); }

Вы пытаетель константу запихать в не константу.
И наверняка видете ошику *conversion for argument 1 from const char...*
Когда вы передаёте const char* ("foo") в Object(string &n) 
Будет неявно создан const std::string.

Если создавать объект вот так

```
 string f("ss");
 Object FAI(f);
```

То прокатит.
п.с. Но передавать строку лучше по константной ссылке